# Tkinter - How to handover list between functions?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, return

I would like to create a list in a function and append a value to this list by clicking a `Button`.

With the button `Check`, I would like to check the content of the list. But the list is probably not known in this function.

Could you please explain me with this simple example how I can handover the list from the function `pressButton100` to the function `checkList()`?

```
import tkinter as tk


# Define what happens when press Button100
def pressButton100():
    liste = []
    liste.append(100)

#Define what happens when press Button Check
def checkList(liste):
    pressButton100(liste)

# Create Window
app = tk.Tk()

# Create Button100
Button100 = tk.Button(app, text="100", command=lambda:pressButton100())
ButtonCheck = tk.Button(app, text="check", command=lambda:checkList())

# Pack Button100
Button100.pack()
ButtonCheck.pack()

# Mainloop
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you want to provide args to a button function you need to:

```py
from functools import partial
```

and change this:

```
ButtonCheck = tk.Button(app, text="check", command=lambda:checkList())
```

into this:

```
ButtonCheck = tk.Button(app, text="check", command=partial(checkList, liste))
```

second of all, in order to achieve your goal of accessing your `liste`, you must define `liste` `globally`, so there is one approach:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
 
# Define what happens when press Button100
liste = []
def pressButton100():
    global liste
    liste.append(100)

#Define what happens when press Button Check
def checkList(liste):
    pressButton100(liste)

# Create Window
app = tk.Tk()

# Create Button100
Button100 = tk.Button(app, text="100", command=lambda:pressButton100())
ButtonCheck = tk.Button(app, text="check", command=partial(checkList, liste))

# Pack Button100
Button100.pack()
ButtonCheck.pack()

# Mainloop
app.mainloop()
```

it is **impossible** to `handover` `liste` from tkinter button function to another tkinter button function, because they have `local` scope.

and `partial()` is a useful tool that tells the button that the `command` is going the receive a `parameter`.

also, another approach(parsing `liste` to every button function) is this (best approach):

```
liste = []
def pressButton100(liste):
    liste.append(100)

#Define what happens when press Button Check
def checkList(liste):
    pressButton100(liste)

Button100 = tk.Button(app, text="100", command=partial(pressButton100, liste))
ButtonCheck = tk.Button(app, text="check", command=partial(checkList, liste))
```

another approach is using OOP, make a class for your app:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TkinterApplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.liste = []
        self.app = tk.Tk()
        self.Button100 = tk.Button(app, text="100", command=self.pressButton100)
        self.ButtonCheck = tk.Button(app, text="check", command=self.checkList)

        self.Button100.pack()
        self.ButtonCheck.pack()

    def pressButton100(self):
        self.liste.append(100)

    def checkList(self):
        self.pressButton100()

    def run(self):
        self.app.mainloop()
```

as a result, `liste` will have global scope only in your application class.

Comment: Using a global variable is hardly best approach. Global variables have long be considered harmful. Don't confuse "best" with "easy to implement".

Comment: yea, but you have another solution to this context? (that doesnt include global scope)

Comment: See answer I just posted.

Comment: @alexzander OOP can get rid of `global`.

Comment: yea, just a minute ago, i remembered about this option.

Comment: hi together, I decided to create a class like in the upper example. I also tried your example with the global list which was also working but I often read to avoid gloabls, thats why I chose the way from martineau. 
Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it and avoid using a global variable or having to create `partial` functions is to use a `class` to do everything. This is because data can be stored in class instance attributes prefixed with `self.` that all methods of the class have access to because they all automatically receive it as their first argument. **This means you don't have to "handover" the list between functions.**

Below is how that could be done with code similar to what's in your question:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        self.liste = []

        Button100 = tk.Button(root, text="100", command=self.pressButton100)
        Button100.pack()
        ButtonCheck = tk.Button(root, text="check", command=self.checkList)
        ButtonCheck.pack()

        root.mainloop()

    def pressButton100(self):  # Button100 callback
        self.liste.append(100)

    def checkList(self):  # ButtonCheck callback
        self.pressButton100()


App()
```

Comment: First of all sorry for the late response and thanks for you answer.
I added a class like in your example and do not have to change the variable between the functions anymore. Thank you very much!